# Is there a PHP port of Java's Matcher class?

Tags: java, php, regex, preg-replace-callback

I'm porting YUI's [CssCompressor](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/blob/master/src/com/yahoo/platform/yui/compressor/CssCompressor.java), which has several [Matcher](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html&rct=j&q=java%20matcher&ei=gs6ZTsWIJa_IsQLO2eHNBA&usg=AFQjCNGutJxfYmy4w3yoE04HegjfyzfixQ&cad=rja) uses, to PHP. For the sake of long-term maintenance I'd like to keep the PHP port as similar to the Java original as possible (`preg_replace_callback` of course works, but drastically changes the program flow).

So, **has anyone ported Matcher to PHP?**

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `YUICompressor.php`? http://code.google.com/p/minify/source/browse/trunk/min/lib/Minify/YUICompressor.php Writing your own port sounds like a maintenance headache.

Comment: @MattBall because that's a wrapper for Java, which is commonly not available on shared hosting.

Comment: Sounds like no one has - sounds like a fun project!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the `while(find next match){ do stuff }` equivalent in PHP (without using `preg_match_all`)?

In that case use `preg_match` with the offset parameter. For example:

```
offset = 0;
while(preg_match(re, str, matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, offset)){
    offset = matches[0][1] + strlen(matches[0][0]);

    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I'm already using this technique in [my own port](http://code.google.com/p/mrclay/source/browse/trunk/php/java/util/regex/Matcher.php), which isn't complete.